# How to cancel/abort/stop an Azure Durable Activity function ( ActivityTrigger ) from outside ( event and/or a timer )

Tags: c#, azure, timeout, terminate, abort

I have an Azure Durable Activity function which looks something like this:

`

```
    [FunctionName("DurableFunction_Ship")]
    public static string Ship([ActivityTrigger] string activityInput, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"The order is {activityInput}.");

        while(true) {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            log.LogInformation($"===> DurableFunction_Ship simulating long running process... <===");

        }

        return $"The order is {activityInput}!";
    }
```

`

Its being triggered by an Orchestrator function that looks something like this:

`

```
    [FunctionName("DurableFunction_Orchestrator")]
    public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        var outputs = new List<string>();

        outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("DurableFunction_Ship", "shipped"));

        return outputs;
    }
```

`

I'd like to be able to trigger some sort of a "cancel/abort" so that DurableFunction_Ship" ActivityTrigger function is stopped. ( So that i can break out of the while loop )

Ideally id like to be able to do it with:

1.An outside event like an HttpTrigger

2.A timed event, like a timer that upon expiration would signal the DurableFunction_Ship to abort/stop and return whatever result back to Orchestrator.

I have tried to use cancelation token and pass it from the Orchestrator into the Activity function, but it does not seem to react to it.

I have tried to use this HttpTrigger to try to stop the whole orchestration but i've read that the " client.TerminateAsync" does not propagate towards Activity functions.

`

```
    [FunctionName("TerminateInstance")]
    public Task Run(
        [DurableClientAttribute] IDurableOrchestrationClient client,
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "terminate/{instanceId}")] HttpRequest req, string instanceId)
    {
        string reason = "Found a bug";

        return client.TerminateAsync(instanceId, reason);
    }
```

`
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

> Stopping an activity trigger is not possible once it has been started, but you can choose to break the steps into more.

```
[FunctionName("Function_RunOrchestrator")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var res = new List<string>();
            string mytoken = "Token";
            res.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Function1", mytoken));
            return res;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function_ActivityTrigger")]
        public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string mytoken, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Mytoken is {mytoken}.Token");
            return $"Mytoken is {mytoken}!";
        }

        [FunctionName("FunctionStart_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
            [OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Function1", null);

            log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
```

> Instance termination doesn't currently propagate. Activity functions and sub-orchestrations run to completion, regardless of whether you've terminated the orchestration instance that called them.

For more information, check this [MSDoc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management?tabs=csharp#terminate-instances)
and [MSDoc2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings.md).